# How to bind Data in conditional ng-style in angular

Tags: angularjs

```
 <div ng-click="uploadwall($event)"
      ng-style="{{ wall.pic && {'background-image':'data:image/jpeg;base64,wall.pic'} || {'background-image': 'url(img/wall-bg.jpg)'} }}">

</div>
```

the wall.pic is from controller $scope.wall. The Problem is wall.pic is not rendering data.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
ng-style="wall.pic && {'background-image':'url(data:image/jpeg;base64,' + wall.pic + ')'} || {'background-image': 'url(img/wall-bg.jpg)'}"
```

Without the `{{ }}` and you are missing the `url()` part

And btw I don't know what `wall.pic` is but if it is an URL/Path it should be:

```
ng-style="wall.pic && {'background-image': 'url(' + wall.pic + ')'} || {'background-image': 'url(img/wall-bg.jpg)'}"
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ogt5brdb/)

Comment: I have tried this too, same problem image is not coming

Comment: Answer updated there is an error change `'data:image/jpeg;base64,wall.pic'` with `'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+wall.pic`

Comment: it's a base64 image fetching from firebase

Comment: So you are still missing the `url()` it should be `'url(data:image/jpeg;base64,'+wall.pic+')'`

Comment: yes right, I've tried that and solved my problem, but still when data is from firebase databse it is not binding in background-image.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
 ng-style="{'background-image' : wall.pic ? 'data:image/jpeg;base64,wall.pic' :  'url(img/wall-bg.jpg)' }"
```

Comment: could not get background-image.

Comment: what's the issue ? it's not showing or it's not setting ? @user3252143

Comment: it's perfect setting but background-image is not coming.

Comment: may be your path or your `data:image/jpeg;base64,wall.pic` is not correct @user3252143